# ASP.NET dropdownlist binding does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dropdown

In ASP.NET I'm trying to bind the text of a dropdownlist with data from a database. In the list I got all the correct values that are used for that certain column, but the shown value does not correspond to the one in the database. For value B the value is shown correctly, but for the other values it is showing value A.
Does anyone as an idea?

**EDIT**

The DropDownList is used as a column in a Gridview and I tried to add the values in multiple ways. For the Column with value 'Lijndienst' it is working fine, but for all the other it just shows 'Green transport'

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transport">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTransport" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Transport") %>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransport" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="20px" >
                <%--<asp:ListItem Text="Geen transport"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Lijndienst"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Intercity"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Firma Piping"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Firma E&I"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Zwaar"></asp:ListItem>--%>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

 DropDownList ddlTransport = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlTransport") as DropDownList);
        Label lblTransport = (e.Row.FindControl("lblTransport") as Label);
        ddlTransport.DataSource = GetData("SELECT Transport FROM Transport", "Transport");
        ddlTransport.DataTextField = "Transport";
        ddlTransport.DataValueField = "Transport";
        ddlTransport.DataBind();
        ddlTransport.SelectedValue = lblTransport.Text;
```

Comment: Need some more detail about the problem if possible please provide me the code

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: can you post the code that you use to get data from the database? including html code for your dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data is in a datatable try this

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var ddl = new DropDownList(); //represents your drop down list 

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    var li = new ListItem();
    li.Text = row["text to show"].ToString();
    li.Value = row["value of dropdown item"].ToString();
    ddl.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Answer edit after clarification with code in question

So, this is a datagrid that I have and has a dropdown list item within it, this is a working example too.  Althouh the asnswer is VB it should give you enough to work with

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Switching to Product" HeaderStyle-CssClass="centre" ItemStyle-CssClass="centre">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="200px" CssClass="centre ddlMoveToProduct" ID="ddlProduct" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_Change">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
```

then you want to run this in your code

```
 For Each item As DataGridItem In dgSuitableSwitch.Items
        Dim ddlProduct As DropDownList = DirectCast(item.FindControl("ddlProduct"), DropDownList)

        With ddlProduct
            .Items.Add("-- Select Product")
            .Items.Add("Premium Investments")
            .Items.Add("Growth Portfolio (OEIC)")
            .Items.Add("Income Portfolio (OEIC)")
            .Items.Add("Index Linked Savings Bond")
            .Items.Add("Fixed Term Investment")
            .Items.Add("Cash")
        End With
    Next
```

if you want a C# example let me know and ill code it up \ convert it for you

Edit 2

heres the c# version for you, both the text and the value will be the same, but theres enough code in all the snippets for you to add a new list item with text and value

```
foreach (DataGridItem item in dgSuitableSwitch.Items)
{
    DropDownList ddlProduct = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlSSProduct");

    ddlProduct.Items.Add("-- Select Product");
    ddlProduct.Items.Add("Premium Investments");
    ddlProduct.Items.Add("Growth Portfolio (OEIC)");
    ddlProduct.Items.Add("Income Portfolio (OEIC)");
    ddlProduct.Items.Add("Index Linked Savings Bond");
    ddlProduct.Items.Add("Fixed Term Investment");
    ddlProduct.Items.Add("Cash");
}
```

edit 3

when adding the items to the drop down list use code similar to this

```
ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem {Text = "your text here", Value = "your value here"})
```

Comment: The DropDownList is part of a Gridview. It is not just filling it with values.

Comment: i'll edit my answer now that we have some code, give me a few minutes

Comment: I prefer C#, but this way it fills a dropdown with the values. That is going good, but then displaying the value of the database does not correspond.

Comment: can you update your question with your code and ill see whats going on